# Testing divide with minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I made this code and i try to test it with minitest, but it seems that i am not using the right syntax for an exception :/

```
def my_method(a,b=10)
  begin
    a/b
  rescue
    raise 'bla'
  end
end

describe 'my test' do
  it "must divide" do
    my_method(6,3).must_equal(2)
  end

  it "can't divide by zero and raise bla" do
    my_method(6,0).must_raise 'bla'
  end

  it "must divide by 10 if there is only one arg" do
    my_method(10).must_equal(1)
  end
end
```

> **Output :**
>
> > Run options: --seed 30510
> >
> > ## Running tests:
> >
> > ..E
> >
> > Finished tests in 0.001000s, 3000.0000 tests/s, 2000.0000 assertions/s.
> >
> > 1) Error:
> >     test_0002_can_t_divide_by_zero_and_raise_bla(my test):
> >     RuntimeError: bla
> >        essai.rb:9:in `my_method'
> >        essai.rb:19:in`test_0002_can_t_divide_by_zero_and_raise_bla'
> >
> > 3 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

The second test raise me an error, can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should call `must_raise` on proc, not on method call result:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

def my_method(a,b=10)
  begin
    a/b
  rescue
    raise 'bla'
  end
end

describe 'my test' do
  it "must divide" do
    my_method(6,3).must_equal(2)
  end

  it "can't divide by zero and raise bla" do
    div_by_zero = lambda { my_method(6,0) }
    div_by_zero.must_raise RuntimeError
    error = div_by_zero.call rescue $!
    error.message.must_equal 'bla'
  end

  it "must divide by 10 if there is only one arg" do
    my_method(10).must_equal(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Note: This is because if you try to apply #must_raise to an expression that is not a proc, that will already have raised an exception before #must_raise can ever be attempted. By using a proc, the execution can be deferred, and #must_raise can invoke that proc within a begin/rescue context, so the exception can be handled.